# scikit learn: How to check if analyzer parameter from CountVectorize() is working correctly

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, countvectorizer

This is my analyzer function

```
def text_processing(text):
    text = denoise_text(text) #noise removal
    text = word_tokenize(text) #tokenization
    text = normalize(text) #normalization
    text = lemmas(text) #lemmatization
    return text
```

This is one of my pipeline function

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('bow', CountVectorizer(analyzer=text_processing)), # strings to token integer counts
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()), # integer counts to weighted TF-IDF scores
    ('classifier', linear_model.SGDClassifier(max_iter=1000, tol=1e-3)) # train on TF-IDF vectors w/ Naive Bayes classifier
])

pipeline.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

The result is

```
---------------------------------------
Stochastic Gradient Descent Result
---------------------------------------
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

    not spam       0.96      0.94      0.95       142
        spam       0.93      0.95      0.94       118

    accuracy                           0.95       260
   macro avg       0.95      0.95      0.95       260
weighted avg       0.95      0.95      0.95       260
```

If  i remove the analyzer parameter function from the pipeline

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('bow', CountVectorizer()), # strings to token integer counts
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()), # integer counts to weighted TF-IDF scores
    ('classifier', linear_model.SGDClassifier(max_iter=1000, tol=1e-3)) # train on TF-IDF vectors w/ Naive Bayes classifier
])
```

It gives me almost the same accuracy. I'm wondering if the `text_processing` function working correctly or not, how to check this?

Comment: You can call the vectorizer outside of the pipeline on a known subset of your data and compare the actual output with the expected output

Comment: i did that and the vectorizer is working correctly. So, i can assume that the pipeline is working correctly?

Comment: If you're still concerned, You can also use the `named_steps` attribute of the fitted pipeline, or alternately you could use each step individually outside the pipeline and see if the end result agrees with the result of using it within the pipeline.